# Jquery, JSON twitter followers count

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

Consider the following script which is used for counting **twitter followers.** For some reason I get the list twice. I just want the **follower count stats** for the elements in the array. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
echo "<div id='twitter'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var i;
  twitterusername = ['Sinbg','followfog','miniclip','vgames'];
  for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    (function(i){
      $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/users/' + twitterusername[i] + '.json?callback=?',
          function(data){
              $('#twitter').html( document.getElementById('twitter').innerHTML + twitterusername[i] + ' ' +
                 data.followers_count + ' Followers' + '<br/>');
          }
      ) // end getJSON
    })(i); 
  }// end for??
});</script></div>";
```

Comment: You are replacing the HTML of your script tag's parent element.  I don't know if that's your problem, but it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the script-tag out of the twitter-div.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/W3cRv/) the example with the script inside.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/W3cRv/1/) with the script after the div.

Comment: I only see the followers once on both? What browser are you using. I'm on firefox 11.

Comment: I guess i should have noticed that =)

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error with the code you've posted:

http://jsfiddle.net/mLCHX/

You might want to check your php code to see if you are outputting the javascript twice.
Another option would be to clear the contents of #twitter before getting the info.