# Pulling in raw Twitter follower count

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to pull in a basic, raw count of Twitter followers. After looking at this thread

[Jquery, JSON twitter followers count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794526/jquery-json-twitter-followers-count)

and following the link to the JSFiddle, I adapated it in a small way. But the code is set up for more than one username and count, hence the array.

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/yQMXA/

I have it working for one username, but given that is all that I need I'm sure the code could be trimmed down. Any pointers as to how to do so would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get rid of the loop and the array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var twitterusername = 'London2012';

    $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/users/' + twitterusername + '.json?callback=?', function(data) {
        $('#twitter').html(data.followers_count);
    });
});​
```